# Embeddable Javascript Widget to be used on any domain using same Facebook App

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, embed

My app is in Ruby on Rails, and I am following tutorials like this one: http://8raystech.com/2011/11/28/how-to-create-embeddable-widgets-with-rails

I would like to add Facebook authentication to it. The end user will be made clear that they are using (my app) on a different website so giving my app permission is a reasonable step that the end user will understand.

Is this possible with the facebook redirect_url restrictions? I've searched everywhere for an example but cannot find anything!

My thoughts are that it might have to be an iframe. But ideally I want to just have a self contained button, that when clicked, brings up details in a modal on how to interact with it: 1) Provide identity (via email/facebook) 2) Enter a short message 3) Click register.

Comment: Iframe! That's what they are meant for, check disqus, all social media buttons (facebook, twitter, google+), etc

Answer (score 0):

Iframe! That's what they are meant for, check disqus, all social media buttons (facebook, twitter, google+), etc.

Most of these social plugins use a javascript file (which is mostly a loader) who will do two thing:
1- Load the iframe containing the object.
2- Manage crossdomain communication between the iframe and your website.

There's a good presentation about 3rd party app by Alex Sexton here: http://alexsexton.com/blog/2012/08/third-party-javascript-in-the-third-person/ (his blog also have a lot of related content)

And a blog post by Bocoup here: http://weblog.bocoup.com/third-party-javascript-development-future/

Or else, there's also the book by some of the devs of Disqus coming in soon: http://thirdpartyjs.com/

These are my 3 favorites. But there's lot more out there if you google `Third party javascript`.